# Django custom user authentication is not working properly

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-custom-user

i am using custom user authentication model which uses an email address as the username and creates the user but **even if password1 is different than password2 the registration completes successfully.** i am unable to debug the problem.

here is **models.py** file:

```
class UserManager(auth_models.BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password):
            """
                Creates and saves a user with given email,
                first name, last name and password.
            """
            if not email:
                    raise ValueError("users must have an email address")

            user = self.model(
                    email=UserManager.normalize_email(email),
                    first_name=first_name,
                    last_name=last_name,
            )
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save(self._db)
            return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password):
            """
                Creates and saves a super_user with given email,
                first name, last name and password.
            """
            if not email:
                    raise ValueError("users must have an email address")

            user = self.model(
                    email=UserManager.normalize_email(email),
                    first_name=first_name,
                    last_name=last_name,
            )
            user.is_admin = True
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save(self._db)
            return user



class User(auth_models.AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    joined_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', ]

    def get_full_name(self):
            return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    def get_short_name(self):
            return self.first_name

    def __str__(self):
            return self.get_full_name() + ", email= " + self.email

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
            return self.is_admin

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
            return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
            return True

    class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "users"
```

**admin.py**

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
        A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
        fields, plus a repeated password.
    """

    password1 = forms.CharField(label='password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='confirm password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

    def clean_password(self):
            """
                check that the two password entries match
            """
            password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
            password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
            if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("passwords don't match")
            return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
            user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
            if commit:
                    user.save()
            return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
        A form for updating users. includes all the fields
        on the user, but replaces the password field with
        the admin's password hash display field.
    """

    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_admin')

    def clean_password(self):
            """
                Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
                This is done here, rather than on the field, because the field
                does not have access to the initial value.
            """
            return self.initial["password"]
```

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
            args['form'] = form
            if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
    else:
            args['form'] = UserCreationForm()
    return render_to_response('authentication/signup.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the password comparison logic present in the `clean_password()` function  to a `clean()` function in the `UserCreationForm`.

The `clean_fieldname()` function should operate on the field `fieldname` and not any other field.

Also, **when fields validation depends on each other then the best place to place the validation logic is inside the `clean()` method.**

From [Django docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

> We are performing validation on more than one field at a time, so the
>   form’s `clean()` method is a good spot to do this.
>
> By the time the form’s `clean()` method is called, all the individual
>   field clean methods will have been run (the previous two sections), so
>   `self.cleaned_data` will be populated with any data that has survived so
>   far. So you also need to remember to allow for the fact that the
>   fields you are wanting to validate might not have survived the initial
>   individual field checks.

**Code:**

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UserCreationForm, self).clean()
        password1 = cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("passwords don't match")
        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: yes, it worked ! thanks ! but what why wasn't it working previously?

Comment: Your real problem is the method name not declared, I explained in my answer.

Comment: @ShubhamGaurav When you need to perform validation which depends on multiple fields, then   you need to place the logic in `clean()` function when `self.cleaned_data` has been generated fully. It might happen that when executing the code for `clean_password()`, `password1` or `password2` field is still not in `self.cleaned_data` dictionary thereby not executing the code for raising the `ValidationError`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you doesn't has a 'password' field,
you need change the method name to, **clean_password1 or clean_password2.**

> the method you created **clean_password**, will never be called
>   because there is no field called password

```
def clean_password1(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("passwords don't match"")
    return password1
```

Comment: isn't working. still registers successfully even if passwords are not same !

Comment: You can validate this in a clean(), like Rahul said, but the real problem here, is what i said, the name of method.

Comment: still not working ! but moving the logic to clean() works absolutely fine. clean_password1() or clean_password2() doesn't work.

Comment: probablity, have some mistakes in the logical inside the method.
i edited again, with my code. try now.. haha i`m sorry for doesnt bother with the inside logical before.

Comment: i have tried everything but it doesn't work except when the logic is in the clean() method.

Comment: but the method is being called?

Comment: yes it is being called, but it doesn't work. i think clean_password1 0r 2 is not generating the cleaned_data as Rahul said !

Comment: I think they are.. just try print(self.cleaned_data.get("password2")) and print(self.cleaned_data.get("password1"), you will see the value.